# Do I have to land ships that contains parts I will not have access to, before updating addon?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm playing career mode. I have 2 mini-stations at Mun and Minmus. But they contains parts from an add-on that did not have any technology tree entries and I added them as I felt right. Now there is semi-official mod to that add-on, that puts items in tech tree, so I no longer need a custom technology entries.

Problem is, if I'll upgrade, some parts will no longer be available to me, and I have them in ships on parking orbits.

Do I need to land these ships, or at least take crew hell out of them before I upgrade? Or is it safe to upgrade, and ships will stay intact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tech tree only affects the parts list in the *Vehicle Assembly Building* and the *Space Plane Hangar*. Vessels that contain not-yet-unlocked parts will not be broken.

That said, if you already have unlocked the part in the tech tree (by having manually added it to the tech tree and then unlocking it), it will *not be locked* when the tech tree changes. Part unlocks and tech node unlocks are independent of one another in this regard. This is to preserve backwards-compatibility if the tech tree is rearranged, and in preparation for currency to be added. (Currency, as currently planned, will be required to unlock the individual parts, while research points are used for the nodes.)

Comment: Great, thanks :D Will mark as accepted when I'll have an opportunity to try.

Comment: One thing that you might have to do is go through the tree again and make sure that those pieces are unlocked.  If the node is unlocked, then it won't cost extra science.  You just need to select the parts in order to unlock them.